# How to customize the style of the action button in the Snackbar

Tags: android, android-styles, material-components, android-snackbar, material-components-android

I am using the [`Snackbar`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Snackbar.md) provided by the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).
I am looking for a way to customize the style of the ***ACTION*** Button.

[image]

I know that the `Snackbar` uses this layout (`layout.mtrl_layout_snackbar_include`) with this `Button`:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/snackbar_action"
```

but I am trying to avoid to use some workarounds that can stop to work with the next releases.
In particular I would like to use a [**`OutlinedButton` style**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#outlined-button) and a **custom shape** as an **arrow**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the version **1.1.0** of the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can define in your app theme the style used by the action button within a `Snackbar` using the **`snackbarButtonStyle`** attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">

    <!-- Style to use for action button within a Snackbar in this theme. -->
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar</item>
    ....
</style>
```

You can customize the style using:

```
  <style name="Custom.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/...</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
    ....
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/Snackbar.ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Arrow</item>
  </style>
```

With the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** you can customize the shape:

```
  <style name="Snackbar.ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.Arrow" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>

    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

You can obtain an `OutlinedButton` style in same way. Just define a custom style with:

```
  <style name="Outlined.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/...</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/...</item>
  </style>
```

[image]